# Cant figure out color codes in dll

Tags: delphi, colors

Okay this might be a stupid question but I am editing a dll written in delphi and would like to change some color definitions but I cant figure out what format the colors are written in. For an example:

99999999 -> is a bright pink

55555555 -> is an orange

15663114 -> blue

3496 -> a dark red

0 -> black

Some colors are defined with 7 digits:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's BGR format. The least significant byte is the intensity of the red channel, the next significant byte is the green channel, and then blue.

It's much easier to understand when you look at the hexadecimal representations of the values, because the value can be easily broken down into the three channels. Consider the decimal `15663114`, which you say is a dark blue. Converted to hexadecimal this is `EF000A`. The colour channels have the following intensity:

```
Blue:  EF
Green: 00
Red:   0A
```

The other colour values can be understood in a similar fashion.

Now, there may also be an alpha channel to represent the transparency level. That would be the most significant of the 4 bytes. The value `99999999` that you quote is `05F5E0FF` in hexadecimal. That would have an alpha value of `05`. Whether or not that channel is respected depends on the code that interprets the colour value.

Comment: Thank you so much. Weird thing is that I cant find a converter anywhere. Is it so uncommon to deal with these ?

Comment: There are a bazillion hex to colour converters around, you just need to know to use hex

Comment: FWIW, a blue value of `EF` is not dark, it is actually almost completely blue. But if the alpha = 0, then it can't be seen at all, so I doubt that an alpha value plays a role there.

Comment: FWIW, if hex is a problem, the Windows calculator in Programmer mode can convert between hexadecimal (a.k.a. hex), decimal and binary.